# Using preg_split avoiding empty key value

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like to know if there is a way to avoid empty keys in an Array while using `preg_split`.

The problem is that I have an input field in that every input will be split by spaces. In that case there even will be created a new Array key.

So i use:

```
$search_term = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_term);
```

when I will enter `abc` it creates an Array with:

```
[0] => abc
```

but when I will enter:

`abc ...`

it creates an Array like:

```
[0] => abc
[1] =>
```

it`s like it will be prepared for the value. But I would like to know if I can unset this key until it gets some value.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ye...

```
preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search_term, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

probably best to check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) before asking these kind of questions though.

Comment: Ah yes, the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is a good starting place.